# Get account navigation links in another template

Tags: customer, customer-account, header

We have added the customer account links in manually with our local.xml file like so:

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" after="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                <name>account</name>
                <path>customer/account/</path>
                <label>My Account</label>
            </action>
         </block>
</reference>
```

I now need to be able to get this list of links in the header template. I have create a block like so:

```
<block name="header.topbar.account" as="header-topbar-account" type="customer/account_navigation" template="johnsmedleytheme/page/header/topbar/account.phtml"/>
```

Wrapped in the header reference tag. and in my phtml i am currently calling:

```
$this->getLinks();
```

In order to retrieve the customer account nav links. But the array is returning empty.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: are you want to show account link on header

Comment: Yes there will be an if to see if user is logged in or not etc and if they are we want to show some of the account links

Comment: your template is adding correctly in layout ?

Comment: @Marius : I was unaware of this. So i delete my answer. Thanks for that great insight

Comment: that means......only logged in customer will see the link?

Comment: And logged out users will see links to login or create account

Comment: check this link for download https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4yc4fcpsguw5sw/34072.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

1)`create new layout in default`.

```
    <customer_logged_tops>
 <reference name="mytoplinks">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
                </block>
</reference>    
</customer_logged_tops>
```

2)`create an event on controller_action_layout_load_before.`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customer_is_logged_in_newlayout>
                    <class>youmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                </customer_is_logged_in_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_is_logged_in_newlayout>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

3) `update this using event`.

```
 public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();

        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
           ->addHandle('customer_logged_tops');
    }
```

4)just define on local.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="mytoplinks" as="mytoplinks"/>
    </reference>
 </default>
```

Comment: it not test.. totally on concept...

Comment: This is totally new concept for me !. If this works, this would be a great answer.

Comment: plus there is a small error that lyes inside layout file. You forgot to put `reference name="header" />` node

Comment: Cheers for the answer, this may be a last resort test! But right now can you see any issues with what i have done above? And why it may not be working the way i expected it too? Cheers